# RIP Arleen Sorkin, voice of Harley Quinn

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

https://www.superherohype.com/news/545532-arleen-sorkin-passes-away-harley-quinn/

> Harley Quinn voice actress Arleen Sorkin has passed away at the age of 67.
>
> The news was broken by fellow veteran voice actor Neil Kaplan on Twitter. “It broke my heart to hear… the original voice of Harley Quinn, [Arleen] Sorkin has passed away,” said Kaplan. “I adored her work as HQ & as Calliope in Days of Our Lives.”

[image: Tweet from Neil Kaplan]

Comment: No more _puddin'_

Comment: Incredible how she also found the time to write _A Few Good Men_, _The West Wing_, and _The Social Network_.